# Indoor SISO wireless Rician channel performance

Tags: wireless, digital-communications

In wireless communications and when you have a SISO system, multipath is considered to be an impairment according to theory.

Suppose now that we have an indoor SISO  Rician channel (a strong line of sight path accompanied with some multipath), can the existence of these multipaths under some circumstances  be of any benefit when compared with a channel that has no multipaths, i.e. only a direct line of site path?

Comment: At its heart, a yagi uda antenna uses multiple paths to reinforce it's gain and directivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't discriminate amongst the paths you can't use them constructively.  If you can't guarantee that they won't interfere with your LOS signal (as is usually the case) then they are generally an impairment.

MIMO essentially uses the resolving power of an antenna array to send differing signals along the different paths which can be received and discriminated by the receiving array in such a way to benefit the system.

There is another way though, and that is temporal discrimination - different paths typically have different propagation delays. Look up RAKE receiver for a CDMA system.
Whether or not you can use this depends on the bandwidth of your channel - if your bandwidth is too small the multipath can give flat fading and nothing you can do will help.

After some comments where temporal discrimination is classified as a type of MIMO, whilst one could argue that this has merit, my understanding is that the usual meaning of MIMO in wireless communications is applied to the use of antenna array(s) to resolve the multipath.

From Wikipedia:

*In radio, multiple-input and multiple-output, or MIMO, is a method for multiplying the capacity of a radio link using multiple transmission and receiving antennas to exploit multipath propagation.*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO

Comment: This makes sense however, Mr. Muller doesn't seem to agree

Comment: I do agree, Tesla and I are saying the same. If your multipath is worth being called multipath, it will "typically have different propagation delays", and as outlined in my comments below, the RAKE receiver is a way to pick the paths apart. +1

Comment: and as said, nothing in "MO" says the outputs need to be *antennas*. The diversity comes from different channel realizations – in time and/or in space.

Comment: From all your comments you are more concerned about terminology and semantics. Anyway good discussion

Comment: By the way does  Bluetooth  use a kind of rake receiver?

Comment: @cesar the thing is, your question is very much about semantics: you want to make use of the multipath property, but that means you're not actually treating your channel as SISO. But you insist that you do!

Comment: @cesar Bluetooth is a communication standard and as such does not define the way receivers are built. It defines how the signal looks like. So, some receivers might, others might not (I don't think it's a common thing for Bluetooth, though – BT is a frequency-hopping per-hop-narrowband system, where RAKE makes no sense)

Answer (score 1):

> multipath is considered to be an impairment according to theory.

No. Theory does not "judge". Some *human* makes an *assessment* and calls it an impairment. We're all free to disagree.

> can the existence of these multipaths under some circumstances be of any benefit when compared with a channel that has no multipaths, i.e. only a direct line of site path?

Definitely is an advantage, you have a lower outage probability with multiple paths.

**However**, the moment you start to consider your multiple paths as being somewhat uncorrelated realizations of the channel producing different channel outputs that you try to make use of to get a lower outage probability:
Congratulations! You've just transformed your SISO into a SIMO channel. No matter how much you try to call it SISO, it's no longer single-output :)

So, if you want to call it SISO, you can't make use of the statistical independence of paths, because once you do that, it becomes a SIMO system.

In effect: when you call a channel "multipath SISO", you're constraining yourself to not making use of the independent paths. So, then there's nothing "good" you can make out of this. You can, with the help of an equalizer in the ideal case only become nearly as good as the single-path SISO case.

Once you stop calling it SISO, you can make use of the nice math that -MO brings. *This is not a property of the channel, but of the systems we mean when we say SISO or SIMO.*

Comment: How can you make use of the independent paths with only one antenna at the receiver? Suppose they add destructively when hitting this antenna?

Comment: Additionally an equalizer will help only in case of  frequency selective fading. If you have flat fading no equalizer will help

Comment: if you have a multipath channel, you don't have flat fading. If you *had* flat fading, your multipath channel would also not be any more of an impairment as a single-path channel.

Comment: *How can you make use of the independent paths with only one antenna at the receiver?* that's not how that works – if you have an observable multipath, that means your channel impulse response has more than one tap length, and then you can use knowledge about the already received symbols to get to a channel representation that allows you to take the multiple paths "apart" and correct them individually. What your "Maximum Ratio Combiner" does across multiple antennas in a SIMO system is maximimizing the inner product between channel vector and receive antenna coefficient vector. The **exact**

Comment: same principle underlies the matched filter in time, with a single antenna. The point is that it's (for a continuous-valued frequency-selective channel) infinitely unlikely to cancel out *all* of your signal's spectrum.

Comment: I think the key technology you want to look into is the good old *Rake receiver*. You'll see a structure there that has basically one receive branch per path (in the ideal case). If that doesn't look like a multi-antenna system to you, I don't know! Multiple-Output says nowhere that the realizations need to be across multiple antennas – they can also be across multiple times, or even across multiple codes.

Comment: Flat fading can occur when you can not resolve your multipaths and when the delay spread is very short

Comment: Flat fading can be very detrimental in case it is destructive. The rake receiver is a special case and works only in a spread spectrum case where the chip period is very short therefore there is a good chance to resolve the multipaths and take advantage of them. However I still do not see how can you make use of multipaths when dealing with a signal which is not  spread spectrum

Comment: I just explained exactly how you make use of it: each branch of the rake receiver gets the matched filter for *one* path.