# Multipath and antenna radiation pattern

Tags: wireless, dsp

Multipath causes fading in wireless communication systems.

Depending on the RMS delay spread vs the symbol period this fading can be frequency selective or flat

The question is does multipath in any way alter the radiation pattern of the transmit or the receive antennas? and if yes how?

Comment: Did you not notice my comment on your earlier question?

Comment: Could you please repeat that comment? Thank you

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/603286/indoor-siso-wireless-rician-channel-performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radiation patterns of transmitting and receiving antennas depend on their physical construction. Multipath depends on the environment in which the antennas are used such as buildings, trees, etc. In fact, when radiation patterns are measured, it is important to minimize the effect of the environment so as not to bias the measurements. So, in answer to your question, multipath does not alter the radiation patterns of antennas but does alter their performance in a given environment.

Comment: So assuming a SISO link(only one antenna at the transmit and one antenna at the receive), why do we always talk about the detrimental destructive effect of fading and not the constructive effect (if multipaths add in phase)? and suppose they happen to add in phase can this outperform an AWGN channel?

Comment: Adding in phase will only happen momentarily and is not predictable so it is not something to rely on for good communications.